# How to get access to the <HEAD> element of a HTML document using a webbrower control in WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, html, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using WinForms C# 3.5 WebBrowser

I’m trying to get access to the head element in the follow HTML Document:

```
this.webBrowserTest.DocumentText = @”<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test JavaScript WinForms</title> 
        <meta name="description" content="Test WinForms" />        
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>”

HtmlElementCollection headCollection = webBrowserTest.Document.GetElementsByTagName("HEAD");
HtmlElement head = headCollection[0]
```

`headCollection[0]` is getting passed as `null`

Would any one have an idea whats wrong?

thanks

Comment: did you wait until DocumentCompleted? Setting DocumentText causes the current document to be dumped and a document won't be available until the async navigation finish parsing the new document.

Answer (score 1):

Your code to get the `head` tag looks fine. Make sure the document is fully loaded before accessing it. You can accomplish this by doing something like this:

```
// Add a handler for load complete.
webBrowserTest.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(DocumentLoadCompleted);

// Wait until load completes.
while (webBrowserTest.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
}

// On load complete, do stuff.
private void DocumentLoadCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser browser = sender as WebBrowser;
    HtmlElement head = browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use webBrowserTest.Document.All["headid"], if you'll provide id="headid" attribute for head element.

Comment: Thanks Petr but I'm afraid this is not working either. I see that the "webBrowserTest.Document.All" property has a count of zero. Any other suggestions.

Comment: It's strange. Following works for me:
        `private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText=@"<html>
    <head id=""headid"">
        <title>Test JavaScript WinForms</title> 
        <meta name=""description"" content=""Test WinForms"" />        
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>";
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = webBrowser1.Document.All["headid"].OuterHtml;
        }`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried

```
webBrowserTest.Document.All["HEAD"]; // or head
```

Comment: Thanks abatishchev. Please, see my comment to Petr above - "webBrowserTest.Document.All" has a count of zero.

Comment: @hungoverbunny: Use `WebBrowser.Document.Write()` method instead.